# I have installed QT4.8.7 but CMAKE could not match the path

Tags: compiling, qt, paths, cmake

I got the error message

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_QTOPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR QT_QTOPENGL_LIBRARY
  QT_QTMULTIMEDIA_INCLUDE_DIR QT_QTMULTIMEDIA_LIBRARY QT_PHONON_INCLUDE_DIR
  QT_PHONON_LIBRARY) (found version "4.8.6")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1333 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

the QT4.8.7 path is  `/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.7`
how to match them ?

Comment: What are you compiling? I can try to do it and then write the steps to follow.

Comment: i am trying to run this open source code
https://github.com/DropIn/SequentialTextReading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable when running cmake. Set it to the path where the `*.cmake` files of the desirable Qt installation are located:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.7/<something-something>/lib/cmake/ ../myproject
```

(but I'm actually not sure if the Qt4 has that cmake directory)

---

Also, the version that comes with the OS can be used. It can't find some modules: probably `libqt4-opengl` is not installed. Get it with `apt-get`.

Get dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install qtmobility-dev libopencv-dev libtesseract-dev flite1-dev libphonon-dev
```

Edit `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
diff --git a/CMakeLists.txt b/CMakeLists.txt
index 8b643ab..ffafc6b 100644
--- a/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -2,7 +2,9 @@ cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
 project (TextReading) 

 find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
-find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED QtGui QtOpenGL QtXml QtMultimedia Phonon)
+find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED QtGui QtOpenGL QtXml Phonon)
+find_package(QtMobility REQUIRED MultimediaKit)
+include_directories(${QTMOBILITY_INCLUDE_DIRS})
 find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc video highgui)
 # find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)

@@ -151,5 +153,7 @@ target_link_libraries(TextReading
     ${MathGL_LIB}
     ${Flite_LIBS}
     ${QEXTSERIALPORT_LIBS}
+    ${QTMOBILITY_LIBRARIES}
+    udev
     )
```

Put into `/usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindQtMobility.cmake` the following:

```
# - Try to find the QtMobility libraries
#
# This module will search for the QtMobility libraries.
#
# It supports both a minimum version and searching for individual
# components. For the minimum version, use
# find_package(QtMobility 1.2.0). For specific components, use
# find_package(QtMobility COMPONENTS ...). See below for a list of known
# components.
#
# Once done this will define
#  QTMOBILITY_FOUND - QtMobility and all specified components were found.
#  QTMOBILITY_INCLUDE_DIR - Include directory for global QtMobility files.
#  QTMOBILITY_INCLUDE_DIRS - All found QtMobility components' include dirs.
#  QTMOBILITY_LIBRARIES - All found QtMobility components' libraries.
#  QTMOBILITY_VERSION - The version of QtMobility that was found.
#
# For each found component the following will be defined:
#  QTMOBILITY_{COMPONENT}_INCLUDE_DIR - The include directory for the component.
#  QTMOBILITY_{COMPONENT}_LIBRARY - The location of the library for the component.
#
# Note that searching for components will be limited to the specified components
# if the components option is used.
#
# Copyright (c) 2011 Arjen Hiemstra <ahiemstra@heimr.nl>
# Redistribution and use is allowed according to the terms of the BSD license.

set(QTMOBILITY_COMPONENTS
    Bearer
    Connectivity
    Contacts
    Feedback
    Gallery
    Location
    Messaging
    MultimediaKit
    Organizer
    PublishSubscribe
    Sensors
    ServiceFramework
    SystemInfo
    Versit
)

if (QtMobility_FIND_COMPONENTS)
  foreach (component ${QtMobility_FIND_COMPONENTS})
    string(TOUPPER ${component} _COMPONENT)
    set(QTMOBILITY_USE_${_COMPONENT} 1)
  endforeach (component)
endif (QtMobility_FIND_COMPONENTS)

find_path(QTMOBILITY_INCLUDE_DIR qmobilityglobal.h PATH_SUFFIXES QtMobility)

#Find the mobility version
if(QTMOBILITY_INCLUDE_DIR)
    file(READ "${QTMOBILITY_INCLUDE_DIR}/qmobilityglobal.h" _qtmobility_global_header LIMIT 2000)
    string(REGEX MATCH "#define QTM_VERSION_STR \"([0-9.]*)\"" _qtmobility_version_match  "${_qtmobility_global_header}")
    set(QTMOBILITY_VERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")
    message(STATUS "QtMobility Version ${QTMOBILITY_VERSION} detected")
endif(QTMOBILITY_INCLUDE_DIR)

set(QTMOBILITY_VARIABLES "QTMOBILITY_INCLUDE_DIR")
set(QTMOBILITY_INCLUDE_DIRS ${QTMOBILITY_INCLUDE_DIR})

#A list of files to find for specific components
set(QTMOBILITY_FIND_FILES
    QNetworkConfiguration #Bearer
    QBluetoothSocket #Connectivity
    QContact #Contacts
    QFeedbackInterface #Feedback
    QAbstractGallery #Gallery
    QLandmark #Location
    QMessage #Messaging
    QMediaPlayer #MultimediaKit
    QOrganizerItem #Organizer
    QValueSpace #PublishSubscribe
    QSensor #Sensors
    QService #ServiceFramework
    QSystemInfo #SystemInfo
    QVersitDocument #Versit
)

list(LENGTH QTMOBILITY_COMPONENTS _component_count)
math(EXPR _component_count "${_component_count} - 1")
foreach (index RANGE ${_component_count})
    list(GET QTMOBILITY_COMPONENTS ${index} component)
    list(GET QTMOBILITY_FIND_FILES ${index} file)
    string(TOUPPER ${component} _COMPONENT)
    if (NOT QtMobility_FIND_COMPONENTS OR QTMOBILITY_USE_${_COMPONENT})
        message(STATUS "Looking for QtMobility Component \"${component}\"")
        find_path(QTMOBILITY_${_COMPONENT}_INCLUDE_DIR ${file} PATH_SUFFIXES Qt${component})
        find_library(QTMOBILITY_${_COMPONENT}_LIBRARY NAMES Qt${component})
        list(APPEND QTMOBILITY_VARIABLES "QTMOBILITY_${_COMPONENT}_INCLUDE_DIR" "QTMOBILITY_${_COMPONENT}_LIBRARY")
        list(APPEND QTMOBILITY_INCLUDE_DIRS ${QTMOBILITY_${_COMPONENT}_INCLUDE_DIR})
        list(APPEND QTMOBILITY_LIBRARIES ${QTMOBILITY_${_COMPONENT}_LIBRARY})
    endif (NOT QtMobility_FIND_COMPONENTS OR QTMOBILITY_USE_${_COMPONENT})
endforeach (index)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(QtMobility REQUIRED_VARS ${QTMOBILITY_VARIABLES} VERSION_VAR QTMOBILITY_VERSION)

mark_as_advanced(${QTMOBILITY_VARIABLES})
```

Comment: _libqt4-opengl_  is already installed

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: i have searched my system for 'CMakeLists.txt' and find more than 500 file !! which one to edit ?

Comment: It's the CMakeLists.txt that comes with the SequentialTextReading project.

Comment: i have added the code to cmakelists.txt and get the error
CMakeLists.txt:155:
Parse error.  Expected "(", got unquoted argument with text "--git".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Comment: It's in 'unified diff' format. Lines with '-' in front of them are to remove. Lines with '+' are to add. Header and the lines with '@@' are to be able to locate where to edit the file. Unified diff can be applied to the file using a `patch` command-line utility. Unified diff can be created with `diff -u file1 file2` or `git diff` commands.

Comment: it is a bit confusing, so could you  please paste the full cmakelists.txt content after modifying it , to help me copy and paste

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/ZcUiC0st).

Comment: thanks a lot my friend, i have tried to link the paths with cmake gui and it works so good

Comment: hi , now i am compiling on another machine using Ubuntu 14.4LTS the following error comes out                                                                                                          compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/TextReading.dir/QExtSerialPort-1.2rc/qextserialenumerator.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/TextReading.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
 i do not know what to do ?!

Comment: There must be a more precise error message in that log. Something with a file name and a line number.

Comment: fouad@fouad:~/Music/SequentialTextReading-master/build$ make
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TextReading.dir/QExtSerialPort-1.2rc/qextserialenumerator.cpp.o
In file included from /home/fouad/Music/SequentialTextReading-master/QExtSerialPort-1.2rc/qextserialenumerator.cpp:33:0:
/home/fouad/Music/SequentialTextReading-master/QExtSerialPort-1.2rc/qextserialenumerator_p.h:66:23: fatal error: libudev.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <libudev.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.make[2]: *** { the previous comment}

that's the whole result

Comment: So, the compiler can't find a file `libudev.h`. Just find which package has that (you can use google search to do that). In this case it's `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev`.

Comment: when running the code here [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=767Tl_-isOg]  I got a segmentation fault (core dumped ) do u know why ?  thanks in advance

Comment: It probably wants to speak, but can't. Try `sudo apt-get install phonon-backend-gstreamer`

Comment: i have installed  _phonon-backend-gstreamer_  and system suggested to install also _phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0_  _phonon-backend-gstreamer_ and _phonon-backend-vlc_  as Phonon is not functional system warning said, please watch the next video Reading just one word [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4bEH7NcdSY&feature=youtu.be]

Comment: I've found a [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389159/tesseract-index-0-index-size-used-errorassert-failed-error) and an [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-issues/JbNaDnxyitk).

Comment: I get this error 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package qtmobility-dev

Comment: @AAI, are you from the faculty of Software Archaeology? It'll become harder and harder to build that project on modern systems. It's probably possible to manually get the qtmobility-dev package and its dependencies from https://packages.debian.org/jessie/qtmobility-dev and then install them with dpkg. Other option is to install an old Ubuntu version like 14.04.